# How to see list of files accessed by app using Instruments in Xcode

Tags: monitoring, instruments

I'm trying to see what files/folders a particular app accesses/modifies

I have Xcode 15. I'm using its Instruments app (v. 15.2)

I choose File > New > File activity. I choose select target, select my app, then hit the red record button. It starts my app and starts recording. After doing a few things in the app, I click the stop button.

Now I have a bunch of data. I see a timeline. I select my app. On the bottom pane, there's a drop down list with options like "filesystem calltree" "disk io reads calltree". But selecting one only shows a whole lot of function calls.

How can I see a list of files/folders the apps reads from/writes to?

I googled but people either omit this last step b/c it's apparently obvious or they mention things I just don't see (presumably referring to an older version).

thanks in advance